# How to use WebMock to mock Paperclip call in a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, paperclip, webmock

This code works fine without WebMock.

Raising an exception:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError:
   No handler found for #<URI::HTTP:0x007ff3852cefb8 URL:http://www.example.com/images/foo.jpg>
# ./spec/support/api_mock.rb:34:in `process_image_for'
```

Test:

```
let( :image_url  ) { 'http://www.example.com/images/foo.jpg'  }
...
stub_request(:post, image_url)
  .to_return(:status => 200, :body => File.read('spec/fixtures/image.jpg'), :headers => {})
...hit Sinatra app...
```

api_mock.rb:

```
def self.process_image_for suggestion, params
  if params[:image]
    suggestion.image = URI.parse( params[:image] )  # line 34
    suggestion.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works. FWIW, both `File.read` and `File.open` work:

```
stub_request(:post, image_url)
  .to_return(
     :status => 200,
     :body => File.read('spec/fixtures/image.jpg'),
     :headers => {}
  )
```

Just remember to `require 'webmock/rspec'` at the top of the test.

Answer (score 5):

it is required to use `headers: {"Content-Type" => 'image/jpg'}` or any valid content type expected by Paperclip

eg.

```
stub_request(:get, "http://img.youtube.com/vi/123123123123/0.jpg")
  .to_return(
    status: 200,
    body:  File.read('spec/fixtures/images/sample.jpg'),
    headers: {"Content-Type" => 'image/jpg'}
  )
```